# Recursively build a query string from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, recursion

I'm trying to recursively build a user-friendly query from a JSON object.

The JSON object can look like:

```
{
   condition: 'AND'
   filters: [
                {
                 field: BooksRead,
                 operator: equals,
                 value: 3
                },
                {
                 condition: 'OR',
                 filters: [
                              {
                               field: BooksAttempted,
                               operator: equals,
                               value: 3
                              },
                              {
                               field: BooksBought,
                               operator: equals,
                               value: 3
                              }

                          ]

                },

            ]
```

This would come out to be something like 
`BooksRead === 3 AND (BooksAttempted === 3 OR BooksBought === 3)`

It's possible to have more groups and conditions nested deeper or further along (i.e. we could have 
`BooksRead === 3 AND (BooksAttempted === 3 OR BooksBought === 3) AND BooksFailed === 0`

The way I see it, there's 3 options when walking through the JSON,

1. we come across a 'condition'
2. we come across an array of 'filters'
3. we come across an entry in the array which can either be (a) an expression: field operator value or (b) another set of conditions and filters

Any tips on how to go about building this string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to ask yourself: What is the end condition for the recursive function? It is clear that the function has to return a string value when it "meets" a JSON-object like:

```
{
  field: BooksRead,
  operator: equals,
  value: 3
}
```

The pseudocode could look like:

```
buildQuery(jsonObject){
  if(jsonObject.hasField("field")){
  // In this case the jsonObject is an object which describes a single query
    return jsonObject.get("field") + " " + convertOperatorToString(jsonObject.get("operator")) + " " + jsonObject.get("value");
  }
  //todo…
}
```

Where the `convertOperatorToString()` method converts your operator to its string equivalent—for example, "equals" to "=".

**Base case (filters' size is always 2)**
Now you only have to handle the case where the initial JSON is not a "field+operator+value" JSON-Object, but a "condition+filters" JSON-Object. In that case, you just have to call the recursive function and pass the first element of filters, get the result, add a respective condition string, and again pass the second element of filters and combine the result together.

The pseudocode could look like:

```
buildQuery(jsonObject){
      if(jsonObject.hasField("field")){
      // In this case the jsonObject is an object which describes a single query
        return jsonObject.get("field") + " " + convertOperatorToString(jsonObject.get("operator")) + " " + jsonObject.get("value");
      }
      // else it is an "condition+filters" JSON-Object
      else{
        return "(" + buildQuery(jsonObject.get("filters")[0]) + jsonObject.get("condition") + buildQuery(jsonObject.get("filters")[1] + ")";
      }
    }
```

**Extended case**
For the case when filters' size is >= 2 we can simply add a loop which iterates over the filters' elements and puts the result string together:

```
buildQuery(jsonObject){
          if(jsonObject.hasField("field")){
          // In this case the jsonObject is an object which describes a single query
            return jsonObject.get("field") + " " + convertOperatorToString(jsonObject.get("operator")) + " " + jsonObject.get("value");
          }
          // else it is an "condition+filters" JSON-Object
          else{
            // We assume that filters always has at least 2 elements
            i = 0;
            result = "(";
            filterArray = jsonObject.get("filters");
            while(i < filterArray.size()){
              // Add (maybe nested) expression
              result += " " + buildQuery(filterArray[i]) + " ";
              // if we are already at the end of our filters array, do not add condition string
              // or we WOULD end up with something like ( a OR b OR c OR )
              if(i != filterArray.size() - 1){
                result += jsonObject.get("condition");
              }
              i++;
            }
            result += ")";
            return result;
          }
        }
```

This was typed directly here on the editor, so there may be minor errors; however, I hope that the pseudocode helps you out. If you still have questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. This makes sense and should be the approach I take in terms of base case. How would we go about adding in parentheses and in the case there are multiple conditions? i.e. one OR has to join 3 conditions ( a OR b OR c )

Comment: @Steve Please check my updated answer. What programming language are you using? Dont forget to upvote the answer if it solves your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

There is a built in function for this `JSON.stringify(object)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

```js
const obj = { data: 123 };

const string = JSON.stringify(obj);

console.log(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually you'd represent `and` and `or` as binary operators with `left` & `right` nodes and negations with as unary operators for instance.

Translating, executing, etc. such expression tree can be done by recursively visiting each nodes.

This implementation doesn't deal with parenthesis simplification, but it should give you the basis you need to implement what you want. You can obviously simplify the expression tree (e.g. make value nodes primitive values) and change it's overall structure, but having the binary/unary node abstractions allows to treat `&&,||,=,>=` etc the same way.

e.g.

```js
const expr1 = {
    type: 'binary',
    op: '&&',
    left: {
        type: 'binary',
        op: '>=',
        left: {
            type: 'id',
            name: 'var1'
        },
        right: {
            type: 'number',
            value: 1
        }
    },
    right: {
        type: 'binary',
        op: '||',
        left: {
            type: 'unary',
            op: '!',
            inner: {
                type: 'id',
                name: 'var2'
            }
        },
        right: {
            type: 'binary',
            op: '=',
            left: {
                type: 'id',
                name: 'var3'
            },
            right: {
                type: 'string',
                value: 'some string'
            }
        }
    }
};

const expr2 = {
    type: 'binary',
    op: '&&',
    left: {
        type: 'binary',
        op: '=',
        left: {
            type: 'id',
            name: 'BooksRead'
        },
        right: {
            type: 'number',
            value: 3
        }
    },
    right: {
        type: 'binary',
        op: '||',
        left: {
            type: 'binary',
            op: '=',
            left: {
                type: 'id',
                name: 'BooksAttempted'
            },
            right: {
                type: 'number',
                value: 3
            }
        },
        right: {
            type: 'binary',
            op: '=',
            left: {
                type: 'id',
                name: 'BooksBought'
            },
            right: {
                type: 'number',
                value: 3
            }
        }
    }
};

console.log(exprToString(expr1));
console.log(exprToString(expr2));

function exprToString(node) {
    switch (node.type) {
        case 'binary':
            return binaryToString(node);
        case 'unary':
            return `${node.op}${exprToString(node.inner)}`;
        case 'id':
            return node.name;
        case 'number':
            return node.value;
        case 'string':
            return `"${node.value}"`;
        default:
            throw new Error(`Unknown node type '${node.type}'.`);
    }
}

function binaryToString(node) {
    return `(${exprToString(node.left)} ${node.op} ${exprToString(node.right)})`;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This could do the job, with minor drawbacks :

```js
let main = JSON.parse("{\"condition\":\"AND\",\"filters\":[{\"field\":\"BooksRead\",\"operator\":\"equals\",\"value\":3},{\"condition\":\"OR\",\"filters\":[{\"field\":\"BooksAttempted\",\"operator\":\"equals\",\"value\":3},{\"field\":\"BooksBought\",\"operator\":\"equals\",\"value\": 3}]}]}");


/**
 * Parses a condition-structured object.
 * Returns : The string for the given object.
 */
function parseCondition(obj) {
    var filterStrs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < obj.filters.length; i++) {
        var currStr = parseConditionOrOperator(obj.filters[i]);
        filterStrs.push(currStr);
    }
    return "(" + filterStrs.join(" " + obj.condition + " ") + ")"
}

/**
 * Parses an operator-structured object.
 * Returns : The string for the given object.
 */
function parseOperator(obj) {
    switch(obj.operator) {
        case 'equals':
            return obj.field + " === " + obj.value;
        case 'notequals':
            return obj.field + " !== " + obj.value;
        default:
            throw "Cannot parse operator : specified operator is invalid";
    }
}

/**
 * Determines if the given object is an operator, a condition, or, if implemented, another kind of object, and calls the corresponding function.
 * Returns : The string for the given object.
 */
function parseConditionOrOperator(obj) {
    if (obj.condition) {
        return parseCondition(obj);
    } else if (obj.operator) {
        return parseOperator(obj);
    } else {
        throw "Cannot parse object : Is neither a condition nor an operator";
    }
}

console.log(parseConditionOrOperator(main));
```

Drawbacks :

- The resulting string will always start and end with a parenthesis.
- The code assumes all operators are executed before all conditions.

However, you can have more than two filters for your conditions and the code will execute properly. You can also add more conditions/operators as you wish, and even implement other kind of objects (that is, something else than conditions and operators.)

I still recommend you read [@L. John's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61880474/recursively-build-a-query-string-from-json-object/61880647#answer-61880689)

Comment: Thanks for the help! Appreciate it. This helped me go in the right direction.